# Push notifications delay with GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

do i need to upload my application apk on google play store to speed up gcm push notification? I am getting push notification but it delay 30 to 50sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to upload it to Google play store
Check you Internet speed or the Api you are using to send the notifications, Usually the Api you are using to send the GCM Notification is taking time.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to upload it to Google Play to use it.

Consider the `ping rate` of your local network. Could be some delay in your network. Try with other network to compare the result first.

Answer (score 0):

For GCM, 
Request is sent from your server to google server with the id's you want to send message to.
Your Server -> Goole Server -> User
So its all network based. Sit back and wait for it to come :)